# Environment variables are not getting expanded in servlet.xml under JBoss

Tags: spring, jboss, environment-variables, web.xml, openshift

Problem:
When I embed environment variables in my context XML, they are expanded when I run locally.  But when I deploy on OpenShift they do not. They resolve to null.

Configuration:
web.xml:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/springapp.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

springapp.xml:

```
<bean id="datasource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://#{systemProperties['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST']}:#{systemProperties['OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT']}/prepare?characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
        <property name="username"  value="AAA"/>
        <property name="password" value="BBB"/>
</bean>
```

pom.xml:

- Spring version 3.2.0.RELEASE

local development environment:

- Intellij (Environment variables set in config)
- Tomcat7

OpenShift environment:

- Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0)
- Environment Variables set by OpenShift.  I confirmed the values with 'env' command.
  OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT=3306
  OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST=127.3.xxx.yyy

The message on OpenShift (note that the server and port are null):

> org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver
>   of class 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver' for connect URL
>   'jdbc:mysql://:/prepare?characterEncoding=UTF-8'

Comment: There's datasource preconfigured in your repo's .openshift/config/context.xml file.  You can use that or as an example.

Comment: That might be a viable solution.  Sadly I don't know how to convert my sessionFactory bean to use the Resource in context.xml.

Comment: Nam, I implemented your idea.  See Answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to configuring for local development and OpenShift JBoss.

I finally gave up trying to expand env variables.  Worked fine with straight tomcat, but total no go with JBoss.  So I switched to Nam's method.

OpenShift created a correct jdbc connection in context.xml, as Nam said.  So I needed the same on my local machine.  I duplicated that by placing this in /usr/local/Cellar/tomcat/7.0.39/libexec/conf/context.xml:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/MysqlDS"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/prepare?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              username="AAA"
              password="BBB"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxActive="20"
              maxIdle="5"
              maxWait="10000"
              />
```

Then I removed `<bean id=datasource...`  from springapp.xml.

Finally I changed the dataSource property for the sessionFactory to:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <bean class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
            <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/MysqlDS"/>
            <property name="resourceRef" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.xxx.yyy.zzz"/>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect"> org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLMyISAMDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Now the context.xml for tomcat takes care of local configuration.  The spring bean definitions have the appropriate info.